# Ifelse with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use dplyr in replacing NA value in the DV column of each ID with DV value at a specific time point within that individual:

- I want to replace NA (DV column) at the time 2 of each ID with DV value at time 4 of that specific ID.
- I want to replace NA (DV column) at the time 4 of each ID with DV value at time 0 of that specific ID.

I can not figure out how to do it with dplyr.
Here is my dataset:

```
ID   TIME  DV
1      0   5
1      2   NA
1      4   4 
2      0   3
2      2   3
2      4   NA
3      0   7
3      2   NA
3      4   9
```

Expected output:

```
ID   TIME  DV
1      0   5
1      2   4
1      4   4 
2      0   3
2      2   3
2      4   3
3      0   7
3      2   9
3      4   9
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `fill` after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(ID, TIME) %>%
   # or as @r2evans mentioned
   #arrange(ID, factor(TIME, levels = c(0, 2, 4))) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   fill(DV, .direction = 'downup')
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID  TIME    DV
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     0     5
#2     1     2     4
#3     1     4     4
#4     2     0     3
#5     2     2     3
#6     2     4     3
#7     3     0     7
#8     3     2     9
#9     3     4     9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), TIME = c(0L, 
2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 4L), DV = c(5L, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, 
7L, NA, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: @OneyKanta i would add `arrange` before the `group_by`, if it is not orderd so that 2 will be always after 0 and 4 after 2

Comment: I wonder if the rules (if is.na(2) then 4, if is.na(4) then 0) can complicate things a little.

Comment: An alternative that honors this would be to `factor(TIME)`, order them per the rules, then `fill` down. (Perhaps un-`factor`ing time after that.)

Comment: I tried your code. However, my whole dataset does not contain missing data with the same pattern. I want to specify replace data within each individual: 1) miss DV at time 0 replace with DV at time 2, 2) miss DV at time 2 replace with DV at time 0, 3)  miss DV at time 4 replace with DV at time 2. Thanks!

Comment: @OneyKanta I guess the `arrange` in the updated solution should work with the conditions you mentioned, because now, it is always 0 comes before 2, and 4 before 2

Comment: @r2evans How can I code (if is.na(2) then 4, if is.na(4) then 0)in dplyr?

Comment: Did you see my answer??

Comment: Oney, your rules in your comment above are different (and more!) than what you have in your question. If it really matters for the purposes of getting an answer, then you need to be clear and consistent. And that needs to be in the question itself, not buried in comments (which can often be hidden from or skipped by readers). (And your expected output is inconsistent with the amended rules in the comment. When you update your rules, I suggest you update your expected output as well.)

Comment: @akrun is almost working as I expect now I have one issue that the missing NA at time 2 is replaced with DV from time 4 than time 0. I want NA at time 2 replace with DV at time 0. Sorry for bothering and thank you for your help!

Comment: @OneyKanta in that case, change the `.direction = 'downup'` so that it would first checking in the downward direction, fill up the NA then checks the updward

Comment: @akrun  thank you so much for your advice. I got it exactly how I want now :))

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the code above. It really helps! :) Sorry for not being clear, I will try better next time.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @akrun that perhaps `fill` is a good fit in general, but your rules suggest handling things a little differently (since `"updown"` does not follow your rules).

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = "ID", names_from = "TIME", values_from = "DV") %>%
  mutate(
    `2` = if_else(is.na(`2`), `4`, `2`),
    `4` = if_else(is.na(`4`), `0`, `4`)
  ) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "TIME", values_to = "DV")
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#      ID TIME     DV
#   <int> <chr> <int>
# 1     1 0         5
# 2     1 2         4
# 3     1 4         4
# 4     2 0         3
# 5     2 2         3
# 6     2 4         3
# 7     3 0         7
# 8     3 2         9
# 9     3 4         9
```

It might help to visualize what this is doing by looking mid-pipe:

```r
dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = "ID", names_from = "TIME", values_from = "DV")
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      ID   `0`   `2`   `4`
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     5    NA     4
# 2     2     3     3    NA
# 3     3     7    NA     9
dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = "ID", names_from = "TIME", values_from = "DV") %>%
  mutate(
    `2` = if_else(is.na(`2`), `4`, `2`),
    `4` = if_else(is.na(`4`), `0`, `4`)
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      ID   `0`   `2`   `4`
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     5     4     4
# 2     2     3     3     3
# 3     3     7     9     9
```